# How to decode unicode-encoded JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object that was saved to a file using the repr function:

```
f = open('file', 'w')
f.write(repr(my_json))
f.close()
```

The encoded JSON now has leading 'u' characters indicating unicode encoding.

```
{u'messages': 'messages'}
```

This is expected Python 2.x behavior, but now I'm trying to figure out how to decode the string stored in that file.  Everything I've tried has given me the same error:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Help?

Comment: Why did you not write them with `json.dumps`?

Comment: I didn't write it.  I'm just stuck trying to decode it.

Comment: @kid_drew I think Rafael is saying that you should not use f.write(repr(my_json)) to write it to file at the beginning. You should use json.dump instead.

Comment: I don't have any problem even with reading after an `f.write` which python version are you using?

Comment: @skyline75489 - I get that, and I already know about using json.dumps.  My question isn't about json.dumps, it's about how to undo an existing screwup.  The data can't be regenerated.

Comment: @user3467349 Python 2.7.6

Comment: Weird, I can't reproduce your problem...

Comment: @kid_drew Is json.load or json.loads what you want?

Comment: For the record, the leading `u`'s aren't your only problem.  Fake JSON like this will also have incorrect booleans and use `None` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data that got written to the file was json(able), that also means that it's representation should be a python literal.  So... You can try to "decode" it using `ast.literal_eval`.

e.g.

```
import ast
with open('file', 'r') as datafile:
    literal_data = datafile.read()

json_data_decoded = ast.literal_eval(literal_data)
```

demo that `ast.literal_eval` works with the `u` prefix:

```
>>> repr(data)
"{u'foo': u'bar'}"
>>> ast.literal_eval(repr(data))
{u'foo': u'bar'}
>>> ast.literal_eval(repr(data))['foo']
u'bar'
```

Note, there might be a few python versions ([3.0, 3.1 and 3.2](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/)) where this doesn't work.  I don't really have a good workaround for those versions -- hopefully you don't need to support them.

Comment: btw just regular eval works fine for me in 2.7 and 3.4

Comment: json_data_decoded is still a string with the leading 'u' characters for me.

Comment: Scratch that.  I screwed something up.  It worked.  =)

Comment: @user3467349 -- Yeah, `eval` should work but also opens you up to a world of pain if the data you are evaluating happens to be malicious :-)

Comment: Luckily, this was just a 1-off.  We pulled a huge amount of data from a third party and accidentally stored it in a file incorrectly.  The file was like 100MB, so manually making changes would have been painful.